# add some words to end of post in database

Tags: mysql

I have table named `Posts`

I want to add some words to the end of this all posts in the table.

If I wanted to replace a word in my all posts I would use this query:

```
UPDATE posts
SET post_content = Replace(post_content, 'old_word', 'new_word')
```

but I want to add words to the end of my posts, not replace

Note: I want to do this in SQL query, without PHP

Answer (score 3):

It's similar to your example with `REPLACE()` but you would use `CONCAT()`.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

```
UPDATE posts SET post_content=CONCAT(post_content, ' Text you want to append.');
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use MySql "concat()":

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html